# Does my EU residence card count as a Schengen visa for the purposes of entering Argentina visa-free?

Tags: visas, schengen, argentina, chinese-citizens

For visiting Argentina, Chinese nationals can follow the [following procedure](http://csidn.mrecic.gov.ar/en/content/do-i-need-visa-enter-argentina) if they have a schengen visa:

> Chinese citizens - Not born in Argentina- holding Chinese Ordinary Passports, who are going to Argentina for tourism DO NOT require a visa if they have a valid “ USA visa (category B2) or Schengen visa” but must pay an entry fee (AVE) in order to visit the country.

Is holding a EU residence card equivalent to the Schengen visa to obtain the AVE?

Comment: Side note: According to timatic (http://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), an Electronic Travel Authorization (ETA) is also required. Perhaps there is more information on the ETA website?

Comment: @pnuts but American visas are specifically indicated as "B2," which leads me to doubt that the intent is clear in any way.  Does it really apply only to B-2 visas? Why not B-1? Surely, though, if a US green card doesn't count, neither would an EU residence card.

Comment: It would probably wise to contact the [PRC Embassy in Argentina](http://ar.chineseembassy.org/esp/) for a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Argentian consulate in Canada](http://ctoro.mrecic.gob.ar/en/node/804):

> Chinese passport holders who have a valid B2 American visa or a
>   Schengen visa will require an electronic travel authorization (AVE)
>   when travelling to Argentina as tourist for a period up to 90 days.

Therefore as long as you are able to submit an AVE authorization with your residency card, you should be fine to enter Argentina visa-free. A residency card is indeed a form of a visa and I'm not aware of any country denying that for the purpose of visa-free travel.

According to a [Chinese forum](http://bbs.qyer.com/thread-2593775-1.html) you will need to upload a scan of your visa during the process so you will immediately know if it's rejected.

Comment: This does not answer the question: the quoted material is essentially the same as that in the question, and the last sentence is pure speculation.

Comment: @phoog sadly the only way to find out for sure is to spend $50 on paying the AVE fee. Afterwards you're allowed to input your details.

Comment: @phoog post updated with a bit more info

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not convinced.  I agree that it is very likely that the specification by Argentina is imprecise, but I have yet to see any convincing evidence showing how the system actually works (and, I'm afraid, the link you added is not helpful to me because I do not read Chinese, and the machine-translated version I got was too opaque to decipher).  To be clear, my first concern is that if they truly only accept US visas if they are type B-2, then that would imply that they interpret "Schengen visa" narrowly.

Comment: @phoog point taken. I will email their website to clarify.